# Android studio create multiple .iml for app module

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

I have created a new Android Kotlin project using Android Studio. Everything work as expected initially. However, when I close Android Studio and reopen it again a new .iml file is created inside the app module

**Issue**

1. Create a project in Android studio
2. Sync and build the project
3. Close Android Studio
4. Reopen Android Studio
5. New *.iml file is created for the app module

**Workaround**

1. Delete the .idea folder
2. Delete all *.iml files
3. Re-import project in Android studio

I have to do this workaround steps each time android studio launches. Is there any permanent solution for this. My Android studio version is 3.6.2

Screenshots

1. Project

[image]

2. app module

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you have multiple iml files for every module? Can you show the screenshot with the issue and share the sample project to reproduce it?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I have only an app module in the project..Screenshots are added. The project is available in GitHub https://github.com/NikhilVijayakumar/MyBestFriend. However *.iml files are git ignored

Answer (score 0):

This project contains multiple modules, one for the root of the project where you have `build.gradle` in the root and another for the `app` with the second build file. Modules can be also created for multiple Gradle source roots. This behavior is by design and is not an issue that needs to be fixed.

See [the document about sharing the project files](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544839) which mentions that you can ignore `.iml` files for Gradle projects as they are generated on importing.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem myself where with a multi-project gradle build project. Though I'm still not sure how the files were generated in the first place, I was able to solve the issue by removing the appropriate lines from the `master/.idea/modules.xml` file, rather than removing the entire `.idea` directory.

Given the screenshots you shared, you should have the following lines in the `<root-project>/.idea/modules.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectModuleManager">
    <modules>
      ...
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/app.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/app/app.iml" />
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/MyBestFriend-app.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/app/MyBestFriend-app.iml" />
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/R&D-MyBestFriend-app.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/app/R&D-MyBestFriend-app.iml" />
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/Android-R&D-MyBestFriend-app.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/app/Android-R&D-MyBestFriend-app.iml" />
      ...
    </modules>
  </component>
</project>
```

Just delete the lines that shouldn't be there so you're left with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ProjectModuleManager">
    <modules>
      ...
      <module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/app/app.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/app/app.iml" />
      ...
    </modules>
  </component>
</project>
```

Then delete the corresponding files from the file system.

When you reload the project or restart the IDE, the project should load the correct `app.iml` file without generating the erroneous files again.